# How can I retrieve the type of a React context's value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am using a library's context that doesn't export the type of its value. Here is what it looks like:

```js
type LocationContextObject = { /* some properties */ };

export type LocationContext = React.Context<LocationContextObject>;
```

I need to access the `LocationContextObject`, is it possible to extract it from `LocationContext`?

Here is what I have done:

```js
type LocationContextObject = ComponentProps<typeof LocationContext.Provider>['value'];
```

It does work but looks like a hack. So I am wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import { ContextType } from 'react';

type LocationContextObject = ContextType<typeof LocationContext>;
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, although Tobias's answer is more versatile

Answer (score 4):

That's what the `infer` keyword was made for.

```
type LocationContextObject = 
  LocationContext extends React.Context<infer U> 
    ? U 
    : never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=12&pln=7&pc=1#code/FASwtgDg9gTgLgAgEoFMCGBjRAzGUwIBEM6WhwwcAnhCggDJQZpwhQB2Awh3CgB6IAvMlJwAdN3a8BAHgDeCNAC4EAZzgwQ7AOYIAvgD4A3BUo06jZqw6TpcAPIAjAFYosCYcAQMmLNlx5%20RCCUdgATVRFMcVsgmS1sFBgEAFUDBC9vBAB%20VIyshBV2FAA3JKA)